# Split a string based on a delimiter but shift across 1

Tags: python, string, split

I trying to split a string (although numbers currently a string in df column) but am struggling to find an answer anywhere. I think using expressions might be the way forward but haven't quite got my head around them.

> example 1) 12.540%
>
> example 2) 4.555.6%

I would like to take everything to the left of the first '.' and only one number going to the right of the same first '.'

I need to apply it to all different number lengths and the above statement is the only constant.

> example 1 ) 12.5 and 40%
>
> example 2) 4.5 and 55.6%

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "using expressions"?  An "expression" is a very generic term in language syntax.

Comment: @Prune he means probably regex!!

Comment: Apologies, Regular Expressions, unless there is an alternative. I have previously used the following code to split the string in a df column using pd. \n `df[['FGM','FG']] = df.FG.str.split("/",expand=True)` with 'FGM' and 'FG' being the new columns and FG being the original column split by '/'. However as mentioned need to try and shift across  1 to get the character 1 past the delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function should do what you want:

```
def split_string(num):
  s=num.split('.', 1)
  s1=s[0]+'.'+s[1][0]
  s2=s[1][1:]
  return (s1, s2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, have used the def function as was easier down the line to re-implement on what I wanted it to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward problem in string manipulation.  Any string tutorial will teach you the basic operations.

1. Find the location of the period.
2. Add 1.
3. Split the string at that point: grab one slice through that index; a second slice from there to the end.

For instance, one you find the location `loc` and adjust 1 or 2 spots to the right:

```
num, pct = str[:loc], str[loc:]
```

Comment: How about catching a group also? like `^(\d+\..)(.*)$`

Answer (score 1):

If you want regular expressions, catch the groups using this.

```py
^(\d+\..)(.*)$
```

Use this with either re.search if you want.

```py
b = re.search(r'^(\d+\..)(.*)$', string)
b.group(1)
b.group(2)
```

Ex-

```py
val = '12.445.6'
b = re.search(r'^(\d+\..)(.*)$', val)
b.group(1)
Out[24]: '12.4'
b.group(2)
Out[25]: '45.6'
```